# How to count the # of subscriptions per day for a specific month

Tags: mysql

(USING MYSQL)
I need to find out how many people subscribed per day for a specific month.
This is my query so far:

```
SELECT COUNT(user_ID) AS Subs,  DATE(subscription_date) AS Day_Joined FROM Users GROUP BY DAY(Day_Joined), user_ID HAVING MONTH(Day_Joined) = 03 ORDER BY Day_Joined
```

I want the output to give me:

```
subs Day_Joined
- 10   2018-03-04
- 20   2018-03-05
- 30   2018-03-06
```

So far its giving me:

```
subs Day_Joined
- 5   2018-03-04
- 3   2018-03-04
- 2   2018-03-04
... and so on..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should group by for Day_Joined only

```
  SELECT COUNT(user_ID) AS Subs
       , DATE(subscription_date) AS Day_Joined
  FROM Users
  GROUP BY DATE(subscription_date)
  HAVING MONTH(DATE(subscription_date)) = 03
  ORDER BY
```

if you group by for user_id too you have not the count  of distinct user_id  ..

Comment: I got this:Error Code: 1055. Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'exercise.Users.subscription_date' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: answer  updated .. again  ..but be sure you are really executing my code and a old refused one .. eventually show me your actula code  ..